# How do I store data in PrometheusDB that can be visualised in Grafana?

Tags: python, python-3.x, prometheus

I want to use an exchange's API and then based on the result, I want to store 0 or 1 in the `PrometheusDB`. After storing this information, I want to plot a time-series graph which shows the single `statistic(0 or 1)` w.r.t. time on `Grafana dashboard`. I am unable to store data in `Prometheus DB`.

I tried reading the documentation(README.md) of a [library](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python). It has many APIs but I could not understand what would be the best method of storing data in Prometheus. I also read the [official documentation of Prometheus on similar lines](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/) and I believe [Exporting to a Pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#exporting-to-a-pushgateway) could be used but I then read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484052/how-to-use-prometheus-to-store-data-to-be-visualized-by-grafana) and got unsure whether this is the right way. Apologies if I am missing basic concepts, would love the feedback on where should I head.

My aim is to write some `requests` code, store the data in DB and then plot a graph on `Grafana`.

Comment: Pushgateway is the correct method for batch jobs. Otherwise, you write an exporter (which is an http service), which prometheus will scrape on a regular interval.

Comment: My logic is custom, I will first hit a URL, check the json response and then store the value in DB. I want to display those values w.r.t. time on Grafana.

For this purpose, Pushgateway is preferable? If yes, could you write or provide me a link to an example? I'd be happy to accept it :)